# Using headers in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

The wordpress plugin has the following format

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: XYZ
 * Plugin URI: # 
 * Description: It is used to ..
 * Version: 1.1
 * License:  GPLv2 (or later)  
 */
```

But the text for license does not appear in the admin side's installed list.

for e.g for Akismet - this is the format

```
Version 2.5.9 | By Automattic | Visit plugin site
```

The text entered for license does not show up. How can I display the text for license using the wordpress format.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress ist not showing the license text anywhere.
See: [plugin.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L38)

Comment: ok... I had referred freely available plugin  as a reference. so does that would mean I cannot make license parameter to be displayed in the Installed plugin list. Is that right?

Comment: Not with the "License" Keyword. But you can add your license information in the plugin description.

Answer (score 0):

You can `use plugin_row_meta` filter to add extra row in your plugin listing.  See code below for detail:

```
function set_plugin_meta($links, $file) {
    $plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
    // create link
    if ($file == $plugin) {
        return array_merge(
        $links,
        array( sprintf( '<a href="https://www.google.com">Your License type</a>', $plugin, __('myplugin') ) )
        );
    }
    return $links;
}
add_filter( 'plugin_row_meta', 'set_plugin_meta', 10, 2 );
```